# How to write Junit test case for code below that sorts 3 numbers?

Tags: java, sorting, testing, junit

I need to write 5 different unit test for the scenario below. How can I achieve that? I am poor on testing so your help will be really appreciated. It would be so nice if you could help me along with the code. Thanks in advance.
NOTE: ALL 5 TEST CASES SHOULD BE OF DIFFERENT TYPE.

This is class for doing the sorting of three number.

```java
public class SortNumber {

    public double[] Sort3(double value1, double value2, double value3) {

        double sorted[] = new double[3];

        if(value1>=value2 && value1>=value3) {
            sorted[2] = value1;
            if(value2<=value3) {
                sorted[0] = value2;
                sorted[1] = value3;
            }
            else {
                sorted[0] = value3;
                sorted[1] = value2;
            }
            
        }
        else if (value2>=value1 && value2>=value3) {
            sorted[2] = value2;
            if(value1<=value3) {
                sorted[0] = value1;
                sorted[1] = value3;
            }
            else {
                sorted[0] = value3;
                sorted[1] = value1;
            }
        }
        else {
            sorted[2] = value3;
            if (value2<=value1) {
                sorted[0] = value2;
                sorted[1] = value1;
            }
            else {
                sorted[0] = value1;
                sorted[1] = value2;
            }
        }
        
        return sorted;
    }
}
```

Class below contains main method:

```java
public class Calculate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SortNumber sn = new SortNumber();
        sn.Sort3(44, 5, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are 6 different possible orders of 3 numbers (not counting cases where 2 or all 3 numbers are equal). You could choose 5 of them.

Comment: in java compare two double number use <，> or == is not right